# slice a dataframe with a datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a datetime index. The index is daily dates excluding weekends.

What I want to do is given a date say 2020-08-28 get the previous 10 rows of a column. So when the index is a numeric index I can use the following line below.

```
data = df.some_column.iloc[n-10:n]
```

How can I do something similar with a datetime index accounting for the fact that weekends are not included in my index? Or should I have an numerical index?

```
data = df.some_column.iloc['2020-08-28'-10:'2020-08-28']
```

Comment: Try: `df.some_column.iloc[:'2020-08-28'].tail(10)`

Comment: @luigigi thanks for that. Just wondering if the date always has to be in '', can it be a variable like my_date?